# Trigger to SELECT schema rows based on WHERE condition

Tags: postgis, plpgsql

I am learning about triggers.

Generally it seems triggers are employed on the backend to perform some action on a schema. I was interested if it was possible for a trigger to return data on a SELECT statement to the main application.

In the table I'm working with we have several string columns followed with a geom (geometry::polygon) column which would contain the WKBT LAT/LONG values.

I'd like to return the rows which meet some WHERE clause AND also return the geom [LAT/LON] in WKBT format. By return I am interested in returning data to the main application.

I seek any examples.

Currently I build a list of all our column names {colA, colB, colC, colD} and then append the following as the last entry: public.ST_ASText(geom).

So I obtain a SELECT as follows....
SELECT colA, colB, colC colD, public.ST_AsText(geom) FROM schemaA WHERE .

So the crux of the problem here I cannot use SELECT * since I must convert the geom (LAT/LON pairs) to WKBT and this must be in the select along with every other column name defined, whether I use that column data or not.  I definitely require the geom column in WKBT format.

This is passed via our DEVART interface.
I was wondering if there is a better way to do this,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "select" trigger in Postgres.

What you can do is to implement a view that transform the data for you.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW myView AS
    SELECT 
      mycol1,
      mycol2,
      geom,
      st_astext(geom) WKT
    FROM myTable;
```

If you need to be able to update the data, you would then put an insert/update/delete trigger on the view, that will manipulate the base table.

Comment: Thanks for the feed back. JGH -- again! I noticed you included "WKT" after the last select column function call.  Is that required?  I have been omitting that qualifier from my select clauses.

Comment: @user9491577 it is just an [alias](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_alias_syntax.htm) for the output column name. You can omit it or set it to (almost) whatever single word you want